# Is my linked list a palindrome based on my solution?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have written the following code to determine if my linked list is a palindrome.
The steps I have taken are:

1. Count the number of nodes in the linked list, to find the midpoint and partition the linked list into two halves
2. reverse the second half of the linked list
3. compare each node of the first and second half of the linked lists to determine if we have a palindrome
4. re-reverse the second half of the linked list.

```
def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:

    if head == None:
        return True

    #Finding the number of nodes in my linked list
    length_ll = 0
    curr = head
    while curr:
        length_ll +=1
        curr = curr.next

    #initializing head2 to be the midpoint node in the linked list
    mid_point = len(length_ll)//2
    
    #reversing second half of linked list
    head2 = mid_point + 1.  #Can I write this line?
    prev = head2
    curr = head2
    nex = head2.next

    while nex:
        curr = nex
        curr.next = prev
        nex = nex.next
        prev = curr
    head2.next = None

    #comparing nodes of first and second half of linked list to determine if LL is a palindrome
    curr = head
    curr2 = head2
    while curr2:
        if curr2.val != curr.val:
            return False
```

I have 2 questions:

1. In my code I have commented out a question 'can I write this line'? My question is whether or not I can simply initialise head2 to be the midpoint node of my linked list. If not, how can I do this?
2. how would I re-reverse the second half of my linked list?

Comment: Why not check for a palindrome using the end and start positions?

Comment: A better and more cleaner approach would be to take slow and fast pointers and reverse the first half along the way

Comment: Shorya, that is what I thought of as well- the 'two pointer' technique. By doing this, is the reason behind it so that the slow pointer will end up pointing at the last element of the first half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So props to @shorya-sharma their solution is definitely the way to go.

That said to answer your question directly.  No, you cannot add that line.
The problem is that midpoint is an integer and head2 must be a ListNode.

Instead, replace that line with:

```py
midpoint = length_ll // 2 # length_ll is already an integer, no need to call len
head2 = head
for _ in range(midpoint):
    head2 = head2.next
```

I'm new to the community here, so please let me know if it's taboo to post links to other sites.

You will find detailed discussions for how to solve this problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=

Comment: Thank for the answer. And I don't believe it is taboo to post links- I've seen it all the time :)